# How to process Sentinel-2 data from AWS

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, amazon-web-services, sentinel-snap

Sentinel-2 imagery granules downloaded from AWS archives (http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com) have a little different data structure than the original granule sub-folders of ESA SAFE product. Consequently, it seems the SNAP tool seems not able to import the data as one product with metadata - and I need to process the data to level 2 (atmospherically corrected ground reflectance). Is there a way? Or is there a site which allows downloading individual granules in original SAFE data structure?

Comment: Just asked the same question on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_process_Sentinel-2_data_from_AWS_to_ground_reflectance), so adding the link for those interested..

Comment: A format change is forthcoming at ESA, did you see that announcement?

Comment: Thank you Markus, I was not aware of that, will post the URL as answer, since it took me a while to find it..

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to marcusN who pointend me to the ESA announcemet:
https://scihub.copernicus.eu/news/News00092
There will be format change shortly, which means also, that the product will be delivered on per tile (granule) basis on ESA data hub.

Comment: Keep in mind that (as of Oct. 2016) this is only valid for new releases of the product. Older data is still in the old product format.

Answer (score 3):

You can download Sentinel-2 data in `.SAFE` format on a per-granule basis from Google:

[Google Public Dataset: Sentinel-2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-datasets/sentinel-2)

Bonus: Downloading of all available granules or searching for data can be scripted with `boto`, `gsutil` or any other library that talks to the Google Storage API.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this Python package that downloads S-2 products from AWS into `.SAFE` format: https://github.com/sinergise/sentinelhub